# Laravel Api - Best approach to format fields

Tags: php, laravel

Usually I use integer for the status, type, and etc fields ...

Example: 1 = Active, 2 = Canceled

But I always find out where to format this data into a string, for POST and GET requests.

And having to do this on the client, I believe not a good way.

So I thought about using the Accessors and Mutators.

Follow how I did it

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value)
{
    switch ($value) {
        case 1:
            return 'Active';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'Canceled';
            break;
    }
}

public function setStatusAttribute($value)
{
    switch ($value) {
        case 'Active':
            return $this->attributes['status'] = 1;
            break;
        case 'Canceled':
            return $this->attributes['status'] = 2;
            break;
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is the best approach, since I'll have to do this in each model. Or do you have a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: a trait would be my first idea here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: @PhilippSander With trait idea will solve and much. Because you have more than 40 models. But each model has its own particularities. So I created an array for each field, so it works dynamically. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way. store the records in database just like 0 or 1 or 2 and while accessing it from the database use laravel's accessors to convert it to string constant based on the value. this remove the need of processing this numeric constants in each controller function manually. accessor function will do that for you when ever u access that field from whatever controller you want. this will increase the clarity in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value)
{
    foreach ($this->status as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == $value) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

public function setStatusAttribute($value)
{
    foreach ($this->status as $key => $item) {
        if ($key == $value) {
            return $this->attributes['status'] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```